# result is disappeared when mobile orientation is changed

Tags: android

in my application result displayed in Text view is disappeared when mobile orientation is changed,for this what can i do.i want my application in both modes means portrait and landscape.for this what can i do.Give me some suggestions.Thanks in advance

Comment: You really need to read the docs about the activity lifecycle. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state for a specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Sairam something fast to avoid that

set in your app activity

```
      android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Answer (score 1):

That happens because activity is recreated when origientation changes, to avoid this you can use Jorgesys Answer, thats if your min Api level is < 13, if is older, you use screenSize too , by other side, if you want to handle it, you work with  savedIntance Bundle.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little dated but has some links in it that should still be very valuable for you.

See: [Android - switching between landscape and portrait mode makes Intent lose values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584779/android-switching-between-landscape-and-portrait-mode-makes-intent-lose-values/584799#584799)