# Turning my phone between vertical and horizontal is calling onCreate of the activity every time?

Tags: android

How do I make it to where the activity persists through orientation change of the device?  If I click in an edittext view, the keyboard comes up, but if I turn my phone sideways after that, the keyboard goes away.

I debugged the code and it's calling onCreate every time I change the orientation of my phone.

Thanks a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - switching between landscape and portrait mode makes Intent lose values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584779/android-switching-between-landscape-and-portrait-mode-makes-intent-lose-values)

Comment: check this tutorial on how to handle an activity state using saved instance state bundle http://www.quicktips.in/handling-activity-state-using-saved-instance-state-bundle/

Answer (score 2):

That's because Android is telling you that the hardware/resources/configuration has changed, there are many application that switches it's layouts or adjust to the new hardware configuration, this applications offers a better perception about the user view.

The method onCreate is called every time that you turn the device, because, maybe you want to build your activity with a layout that responds to the new configuration (screen resolution, i.e). Android needs to get the new screen resolution (i.e.) to pass to your activity and re-build them.

there aren't too many troubles with this because the activity will recreate itself, the problem is that if you do any expensive operation then, when rotation happens the expensive method will be running again and again and again.

The more efficient code to avoid this is saving the expensive operation results into a bundle, when rotation ocurrs then obtain the persisted result. Something like this:

```
//data is the activity's necessary information to build activity data:
MyData data = new MyData();

@Override   
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
  data = (MyData) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
  if( data == null ){
    data = new MyData();
    data = performExpensiveOperation;
  }
  buildLayout();
}
```

now, buildLayout() will build the layout activity with the data's information.

putting this method ("onRetainNonConfigurationInstance") inside your activity you can save whole data concerning to the activity... somethinb like this;

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
  return data;
}
```

later you can read more specific info here: [Faster Screen Orientation](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html)

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1) Lock your Activity to one orientation using the "android:orientation=landscape/portrait" attribute in the Activity's manifest entry.

2) Properly handle configuration changes by saving your app's state in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) and restoring it when that Bundle is passed into onCreate(Bundle) when it reloads itself.

There are many resources and articles available that detail saving Activity state on Android.

Comment: Option #1 is not recommended except for unusual circumstances, where there is no way to really pass data between the old and new activity via `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`.