# Android App to always stay in Landscape

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have looked [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536059/launching-android-app-in-landscape-mode) but am still unable to tackle my problem.

I have recently jumped into android (headfirst) and have been messing around. I would like my application to only run in Landscape mode no matter which way the screen is tilted.

My home screen is basically a page with a background and a few buttons that are aligned on the right side.

Here is my XML

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingLeft = "450px"
    android:paddingRight = "60px"
    android:paddingTop="25px"
//I have tried adding orientation commands here like the one below??
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background = "@drawable/sign"
    >

<Button 
android:id="@+id/Button1" 
android.layout_height="60px"
android.layout_width="30px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:text="Button1"/>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<Button 
android:id="@+id/Button2" 
android.layout_height="60px"
android.layout_width="30px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:text="Button2"/>
```

Comment: bahh thanks guys I was changing the wrong file. The other question i linked to would have solved the problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add this line in your manifest.xml file.

```
<activity android:name=".activity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
```

if you want only landscape orientation then change landscape instead of portrait

see this [How to set android show vertical orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119606/how-to-set-android-show-vertical-orientation/6119822#6119822)

Comment: it seems that where ever this line goes I get an error, and if not it crashes on load.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following property  all the activites in your manifest file:

**android:screenOrientation="landscape"**

for example:

```
<activity  android:name=".MainActivity"  android:screenOrientation="landscape"  "  >
              <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

you can add this property in your **application** tag also in the manifest file .

hope this help you to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` on the activity tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: that is something i have tried too but it keeps throwing me an error. I will give it another shot.