# Android: How to display fragment in landscape mode, even if the phone is in portrait mode?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

There is a fragment, that is in portrait mode, then I replace that fragment with another, and I want it to be displayed in landscape mode, even if I hold my phone in portrait mode. (Both are in the same activity, and I don't want to change that.) 
If I simply put the layout file in the layout_land folder, than the app crashes. I can't define it in a layout xml tag like android:screenorientation="landscape", because i must add and replace fragments programatically. Any idea?

Comment: Activities are portrait and landscape. Fragments do not have an orientation. Hence, there is no concept in Android of displaying a fragment in landscape mode, except by displaying its hosting activity in landscape mode.

Comment: so there is no way to display two fragments with different orientation within the same activity?

Comment: Generally, you are correct. It is *conceivable* that the new animation effects available in API level 11+ might allow you to accomplish the same effect, by rotating the widgets in a fragment to your desired perspective. I have not tried this, particularly for widgets accepting user input, and the classic `RotateAnimation` would not handle this scenario (input would be portrait even if output would be landscape, in effect).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584779/android-switching-between-landscape-and-portrait-mode-makes-intent-lose-values

Answer (score 0):

You could give false informations to your accelerometer litener.. it's not very pretty but should work

Answer (score 0):

Look at

```
setRequestedOrientation(requestedOrientation);
```

Maybe it helps you.