# Activity not recreated on rotation

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

1. Activity 1 created and shown (portrait mode)
2. Activity 2 created and shown (portrait mode)
3. Rotation (to landscape mode). Activity 2 is recreated as expected
4. Press Back
5. Activity 1 is shown in portrait mode (landscape mode is expected with Activity 1 recreation)

Why activity is not recreated?

PS. No orientation set or `onConfigurationChanged()` overriden for Activity 1 in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: add this line to manifest android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

Comment: please check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584779/android-switching-between-landscape-and-portrait-mode-makes-intent-lose-values

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi first tell to him/her to post `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: gets the `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` callback triggered in `Activity` 1 when the device is rotated while displaying `Activity` 2?

Comment: `onConfigurationChanged ` is not overriden neither in Activity nor super activities

Comment: please see AndroidManifest part for this activity in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason my colleague added `activity.setRequestedOrientation(..)` long time ago and it prevented activity from changing orientation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this code in manifest for activity1

add this code:`android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"`

if you have handled it in config changes:`android:configChanges="orientation"`
then either remove it or you have it handle in `onConfigurationChanged ()` callback in your activity

Comment: no special settings in AndroidManifest for the activity:`<activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
        </activity>`

Comment: setting `android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"` for the activity in manifest did not help

Comment: add android:configChanges="orientation" in your manifest and override onConfigurationChanged() to change the view.